# Find a Windows 10 or 11 ISO to install it in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, iso-image, microsoft-virtual-pc

I know how to install an ISO in VirtualBox or Virtual PC, but I don't know where to find a Windows 10 ISO file. Microsoft provide a [tool to download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) but it seems that it's only usable to upgrade a running Windows (I launched the tool with my Windows 7).

Where can I find Windows 10 ISO file?

Comment: The tool can create a ISO I suggest that method or use the trial VMs

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Microsoft now provides Windows 10 test VMs for Hyper-V, VMware and VirtualBox. Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/
2. Under **Virtual Machine** select: **Microsoft Edge on Windows 10**
3. Under **Select Platform**, select the virtualization technology of choice
4. Download the .ZIP file
5. Unzip the VM and import it into your virtualization platform

This VM will allow you to test Windows 10 for up to 90 days.  You can activate the VM by entering your Windows product key which will eliminate the 90 day limit.

Comment: That's very interesting, is it a full Windows or it only contain the Edge browser?

Comment: I tested and yes it's a full Windows 10 system, all the programs and features are here. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck with testing.

Comment: It seems the page is broken :( Use this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Updated the link..

Comment: I need to use 2 different Windows 10 VMs to simulate 2 different Windows network-servers. Is it allowed to download and activate 2 instances of Windows 10?

Comment: @AnthonyBartolo, I have a Windows 10 OS installed on a laptop, based on which I am developing my application. You mentioned that if I enter the Windows product key, the 90 day limit is lifted. Do you mean, that I have to get a new Windows 10 key, and use that to activate that VM after 90 days? Or are you saying that if I have any existing valid Windows 10 key, it should work?

Comment: This is not really "full" Windows, because it's a time-limited version only meant to test websites in Edge, not to be used as a full fledged OS, plus it's not the most up-to-date version of Windows 10, and Windows Update doesn't work properly in this version.

Answer (score 17):

There's another option to download the ISOs from Microsoft. You just have to either use a non-Windows PC (Linux, Mac, Android, whatever...) or use a user-agent spoofer tool so Microsoft's website thinks you're not in Windows. I used this one for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg (User-Agent Switcher for Chrome)

The reason is that if they see you use Windows they'll offer you their downloader EXE, which can only download to drive C: and if it's full (which is usual when using a small SSD drive as the main one) you can't download even if you have a secondary drive with several free TBs, since you can't choose another drive.

If their site thinks you're not on Windows, they'll offer you direct download links to the ISOs valid for 24h.

The URL to get the ISOs is this one (remember to use a spoofer or a non-Windows device or you won't be able to get the links to the ISOs from this page, and will get links to the tool instead):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: is there a expiration date on this ISO as well?

Comment: No, once downloaded within the 24 hour period the ISO doesn't expire.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a few methods to download an ISO - the same page that provides the media creation tool will give you an ISO download when you're not running windows. Edge trivially lets you 'fake' being an ipad in developer mode (ctrl-shift I, then pick some non windows device under Dimensions)

More recently - while its a third party tool, I've been using the [Universal Media Creation Tool](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/c74dc774a8fb81a332b5d65613187b15) - since it lets me pick specific builds (and patches out some of the windows 11 TPM checks) in case I want to run a VM on an older version for some reason.