# How to turn virtual Win10 to 64bit with Virtual Box on Win10 when Hyper V doesn't work?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit

> EDIT: Hyper V isn't compatible with Virtual Box anyway as mentioned in a comment
>   - but I leave it in the title since others might fall for the same issue as me.

I'm running Win10 on a virtual machine and when I try to install a new program I get following error:
[image]
So I check the log file and find this:

```
[20F0:2574][2018-07-26T19:39:32]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[20F0:2574][2018-07-26T19:39:32]i000: Condition failed: This application requires 64-bit operating system.
```

I think: "Oh, I guess this is a 32bit version", and I check it in the properties of the VM, but it says otherwise:
[image]

But then I think "Maybe it's just a label, and in reality it is 32bit indeed." So I google around how to change it to 64bit and I find that I have to activate Hyper-V on my non-virtual Win10 to make it work, so I check all these Hyper-V boxes, restart, and try again (Don't get confused - in the screenshot they're not checked yet, but I did check them).
[image: Hyper-V Checkboxes]

But then the Virtual Machine won't even start anymore:
[image: Fail after Hyper-V Checkboxes checked]

I have an AMD Ryzen 5 1600 six-core processor, in case that is important to solve this problem and my host operating system is Windows 10 Pro 64bit.
[image]
[image]

Anyway, after all this I ran out of ideas and posted my problem here - can anyone help? Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a 32bit version of the program I'm trying to install so I gotta get this to work somehow.

Comment: Hyper-V is 100% compatible with AMD hardware.  If your CPU does not support virtualization then  what you want cannot be accomplished with your hardware.  VirtualBox is not compatible and cannot be ran if you enable Hyper-V.  Edit your question to indicate what your hardware is, and provide English translations, for error messages

Comment: @Ramhound I added the name of my processor, there's no German error msg that is worth translating here, everything important is already in English. If there are any more hardware parts that can affect virtualization let me know and I'll add them. Thanks for the Hyper-V not compatible with VirtualBox information...but I'm more interested in how to make 64bit work in my case.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the system properties, that indicate, you actually have 64-bit Windows 10 installed.  What is your host running.

Comment: @Ramhound alright, I added that information of my host. It is indeed Windows 10 64bit

Comment: @Ramhound AH, I think I found the cause! I checked the operating system properties in the virtual machine, and it says 32bit operating system!! I think now I should be able to fix the problem by myself! :)

Comment: That’s what I wanted you to provide anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80758/discussion-between-ramhound-and-cold-class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought "it's 32-bit" was correct, I just got confused by that "64-bit"-selection (2nd screenshot). Turns out, that selection is correct though, because when I change it to 32-bit I can not start the vm anymore...but that wasn't the problem here.

The problem was that I didn't have a 64-bit Windows operating system on my vm. So I searched around on here, [found how to get it](https://superuser.com/q/961322/658171), and created a new vm. 
For that specific program I was trying to install, I additionally had to turn the RAM up to 8Gb and then finally everything worked!